# TableView properties для редактируемых полей

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

Задача:

Во `ViewController'е` есть `grouped TableView` (две секции) c возможностью редактирования текста в `cell'`ах. Необходимо написать `Input Accessory View` для клавиатуры, добавляющий кнопки "`Next`", "`Previous`" (для переключения между ячейками таблицы), и "`Done`" для исчезновения клавиатуры.

Вопрос:

Какие проперти есть  у полей (или ячеек) чтобы посылать им -`becomeFirstResponder` и -`resignFirstResponder` и правильный ли это вообще вариант решения задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно раздать уникальные теги текстовым полям. подписать их всех на одного делегата, в котором реализовать примерно следующуюю функцию:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
  NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
  // Пытаемся найти следующий элемент
  UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
  if (nextResponder) {
    // Если мы его находим делаем его первым ответчиком
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
  } else {
    // Если нет, скрываем клавиатуру
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  return NO;
}
```

ну и return key переименовывать в зависимости от поля в котором мы находимся.

`textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;`

Comment: Спасибо за решение!